# Time format and conversion SQLite DB

Tags: sqlite, time, formatting, timestamp, truncation

I am not a programmer and have no experience with SQLite. In my current work we were using an Access database to store data collected during systematic research trips via a third part dedicated open source software. The latter has now discontinued support for using Access databases in favour of SQLite or MYSQL DBs. Provided that i have no idea on how the third part software talks to my SQLite DB, my problem is that in all the tables of the DB, including the one where all GPS data are stored, I have several time columns, one for the local time, one for the PC time, one for the UTC time, one for the time a specific record has been saved and so forth... and they all save the Time as e.g. 2018-05-21 07:38:06.246 . Now, for the love of money, I cant find a way to tell my software not to save milliseconds in each of the above columns in each of the tables of the DB. Is there a way to truncate in all the columns/tabs the milliseconds portion of the time fields without rounding the time so that if my recorded time is 2018-05-21 07:38:06.946 it will become 2018-05-21 07:38:06? I use SQLiteStudio 3.1.0 to manage my DB. Thank you very much for your help.

N

Comment: These are valid time strings; why is this a problem?

Comment: They are indeed valid time strings. The problem is that I use time as a primary key to run my queries. Let's say in my GPS table I have the time 2018-05-21 07:38:06.946 and in a different table I have recorded an event at 2018-05-21 07:38:06.146, when i run my query trying to associate the gps table to events table I will have many records missing because of the slight difference at the millisecond level. The GPS table automatically stores data every second but It doesn't save automatically the time and position when I store a record in a whatever other table.

Comment: And what happens when 01:23:45.999 and 01:23:46.001 belong to each other?